# How to remove duplicates from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

What the best way to remove duplicates from an array of objects?

```
var array = [
  {a: 0, b: 0, c: 0},
  {a: 0, b: 0, c: 0},

  {a: 1, b: 1, c: 1},
  {a: 1, b: 1, c: 1},

   //..... etc
];
```

And, i want to get like:

```
[
  {a: 0, b: 0, c: 0},
  {a: 1, b: 1, c: 1}
];
```

PS: the keys (a, b, c) have only primitive data type (String, Number)

Please, without underscore.js and other libs.

Comment: What happened to the `c`s?

Comment: Also, does order matter?

Comment: Finally... why not use underscore?

Comment: What is your equality function?  I.e. what does it mean for two objects to be duplicative of one another?  Are you assuming no-one will mutate elements of this array?

Comment: You should checkout this question, it offers a good comparison method -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: @Dancrumb, the order does not matter

Comment: @Robbin: great... what about the other two questions?

Comment: @Dancrumb, I dont want to use the underscore.js in my project, because there're no any reasons for it

Comment: @Robbin, while you're free to chose, there actually *is* a good reason to use underscore: you want to take an array of objects and remove duplicates. Tom's solution below is fine, if you don't mind O(n^2) performance and if your objects will never change and if there can never be an `undefined` or `null` element, or if... you know, any number of things you might not have though of. Using libraries helps because they are often much more rigorously developed and tested than you have time to do yourself.

Comment: Underscore or lodash or others have precisely the methods that you're asking for, so they're a great choice... unless this is homework... in which case... *shrug*

Comment: 100% agree with @Dancrumb, this is just a simple way to do this for small data, also I didn't check for `undefined` or `null` values, but that's homework ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there is better ways to do this, but you can use this prototype function.

```
Array.prototype.removeDuplicates = function () {
    var r = new Array();
    o:for(var i = 0, n = this.length; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(var x = 0, y = r.length; x < y; x++)
            if(r[x].a==this[i].a && r[x].b==this[i].b && r[x].c==this[i].c)
                continue o;
        r.push(this[i]);
    }
    return r;
}
```

#### How to use it

```
var arr = [
  {a: 0, b: 0, c: 0},
  {a: 0, b: 0, c: 0},
  {a: 1, b: 1, c: 1},
  {a: 1, b: 1, c: 1},

   //..... etc
];
var uniques = arr.removeDuplicates();
console.log(uniques);
```

#### Note:

You should avoid this for big arrays, out there are better solutions

Comment: Could you rewrite your example without *o:* ?

Comment: @Robbin: I think a better idea is that you rewrite the code. *Hint: use a bit (value 0 or 1) inside loop*

Comment: How big of arrays should be avoided, and I have been looking, anyone have a link or can state a better solution, I have the same issue but have arrays with a couple thousand objects to go through...

Comment: @Lion789: In that case you need to study algorithms for that and maybe some heuristics

Comment: Ok, by the way, using the above prototype, how would you go about removing duplicates and merging two or more arrays?